# How can I store my JPasswordField value into MySQL?

Tags: java

I want to design a signup form and the form is contain a `JPasswordField` and I define a `String` variable to get data from my `JPasswordField`

```
String pass = jpf.getText(); 

stmt.executeQuery("Insert into TbLogin values('"+pass+"')");
```

And my Column datatype is `varchar(30)`

Answer (score 2):

Inserting cleartext passwords into a database in 2014 is not a good idea. Really.
Please read up on salting, hashing and bcrypt at least.

Next down the road is the user with the passowrd `some"thing`, which will make your query throw a curveball. 
Please read up on escaping, parameterized queries and prepared statements.

Comment: +1, more if I could. And don't use getText(). It was deprecated in 1998. Use getPassword().